# LinPhone Android sdk integration

Tags: android, android-ndk, linphone, linphone-sdk

I have to integrate linphone sdk in my android project for video calling functionality.

I have research and found the below link to download the sample code

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

and configure with my android studio and install NDK for it in windows7 system but it missing the classes for the running sample.

```
import org.linphone.core.LinphoneCore;
import org.linphone.core.LinphoneCore.LogCollectionUploadState;
import org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreListenerBase;
import org.linphone.mediastream.Log;
```

This type of files are missing in the sample code.

Please provide me the steps to start integrating linphone in my android app.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the instructions under

> COMPILATION INSTRUCTIONS
>
> To build liblinphone for Android, you must:

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

Follow each step and if you run into any specific issue then post it with details so that someone can help you.

Note:

1) Make sure you clone the github repo properly. When cloned properly you'll get all the libraries.

2) Don't forget that you will need to `make` as mentioned in the instructions:

> Run the Makefile script in the top level directory, `make`.

Comment: Is the build can be run directly with the windows7 system having android studio or  i need to run through commands line to generate the build. how to create make ?

Comment: You will need to use a system that uses `make` like one of the Linux distributions. Try to download a Linux distribution like Ubuntu or CentOS and install it then follow the instructions.

Comment: If you find all this difficult then try to use a simpler method in implementing VoIP by using an easy to use SDK like Sinch or ABTO VoIP SIP SDK for Windows. There are some free VoIP SDKs out there but you will need to do research in order for you to properly use them. The paid ones are generally easier to use and the documentation is easy to read.

Comment: @Amir If I integrate liblinphone in my existing app, do I need a voip server to make audio video calls?

Comment: Yes, you do need a sip server. You can use this one https://www.linphone.org/freesip/home depending on how your app will be used or get your own sip server

Answer (score 0):

You need to include liblinphone.jar into your project to resolve the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the instructions [here](https://www.linphonecode.blogspot.in").

Follow each step and if you run into any specific issue then post it with details so that someone can help you.

Note:

1. Make sure you clone the github repo properly. When cloned properly you'll get all the libraries.
2. Don't forget that you will need to make as mentioned in the instructions:

   > Run the Makefile script in the top level directory, make.